# How to find out the sequence of value in R

Tags: r

Supposed that I have generated 100 different value from -100 to 100, and I have `cumsum` all of those value.

```
set.seed(123)
x <- -100:100
z <- sample (x, size = 100,replace=T)
cumsum(z)
```

and I got

```
[1]   58  136   49  143  212  161  178  120   33   50  102   91   81  177  167  251  242  278  276  247  172   78  147
 [24]  183  246  223  203  145  147  163  138  180  111  119   25   61  129  102   24   78  165  117  151  103  157  222
 [47]  155  123   94   69   31   71   67   57  109   46  -34  -94  -20  -31  -72 -157 -142 -149 -244 -145 -160 -175 -237
 [70] -179 -162 -213 -280 -377 -465 -497 -471 -419 -468 -547 -559 -500 -576 -642 -575 -564 -635 -596 -538 -518 -509 -452
 [93] -489 -448 -350 -384 -334 -313 -335 -351
```

Now, I would like to stop or find out the value that is greater than 200 or lower than -200.

If I do it by my hand, I know that the 5th sequence (212) is greater than 200.

However, in R, is there any command to find out the first time that z is greater than 200 or lower than -200?

Thank you very much

Comment: `min(which(abs(cumsum(z))>200))`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think it is a good way to find out z > 200. However, as there is two situation z>200 or z< negative 200. If we apply abs, the negative value will be return to positive. Thus, is there any way to find out z>200 or z< negative 200? Sorry, maybe my explanation is not good enough.

Answer (score 1):

A quick hack way to do this might be:

```
z <- as.data.frame(z)
z$lv <- if_else(z >200,T,F)
min(which(lv == TRUE))
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, what if the value hit -200 at the first time? Should we need to write a command that z is lower than -200? thanks again

Comment: So you would just use the "|" command to augment the conditional statement to "or".

Comment: as in if_else(z>200|z<-200,T,F) (Note: may actually be the logical || so have a play around!

Comment: Yes, I think using "|" is correct. However, if I apply z<-200, it becomes assigning 200 into z, rather than z is lower than -200. How can we avoid this problem? Thank you!

Comment: maybe stick it in brackets or write <(-1)*200

Answer (score 1):

The `min(which(...))` solutions provided by others don't give a convenient answer in case none of the values meet the condition.  For example,

```r
set.seed(123)
x <- -100:100
z <- sample (x, size = 100,replace=T)
min(which(abs(cumsum(z)) > 200))
#> [1] 5
min(which(abs(cumsum(z)) > 1000)) # None meet this condition
#> Warning in min(which(abs(cumsum(z)) > 1000)): no non-missing arguments to min;
#> returning Inf
#> [1] Inf
```

A better way is given in the R help page for `which.max`:

```r
match(TRUE, abs(cumsum(z)) > 200)
#> [1] 5
match(TRUE, abs(cumsum(z)) > 1000)
#> [1] NA
```